Pytesseract splitting a line
I'm new to using Pytesseract, and I'm having trouble recognizing an image:
Bet Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\Tesseract.exe'

# Perform OCR on an image
result = pytesseract.image_to_string('img6.jpg')
print(result)

The Result is:
Poissy Basket +14.5
Point Spread
Quimper vs Poissy Basket
Mulhouse -1.5
Point Spread
Mulhouse vs STB Le Havre
Massagno -1.5
Point Spread
Massagno vs Neuchatel
Treble
Total Stake
R$50.00
1.83 R$’|7.00
To Return R$31.16
1.83 R$’|7.00
To Return R$31.16
1.83 R$’|2.00
To Return R$22.00
6.16 R$4.00
To Return R$24.64
Total To Return
R$108.96
I need something like this:
Poissy Basket +14.5 1.83 R$17.00
Point Spread
Quimper vs Poissy Basket To Return RS31.16
Mulhouse -1.5 1.83 RS17.OO
Point Spread
Mulhouse vs STB Le Havre To Return RS31.16
Massagno -1.5 1.83 RS12.00
Point Spread
Massagno vs Neuchatel To Return RS22.00
Treble 6.16 RS4.00
To Return RS24.64
Total Stake Total To Return
RS50.00 RS108.96

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
